# Windows won't boot after Installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub-efi

Noob here. Installed Ubuntu 20.04 to dual boot on my laptop. However, now in grub the Windows Boot Manager doesn't load Windows.

Looking at Gparted, I'm booting from /dev/nvme0n1p1, but the OS is on /dev/nvme0n1p3. [image: Gparted Info]

When I select the Windows Boot Manager option, a circle of dots appears, it soon becomes a black screen followed by the GRUB menu again.

I'm not sure why I have 7 partitions - this is what happened after Ubuntu's default installation process.

So far, I've tried boot-repair, updating grub, and changing the default OS In etc/default/grub. Running update-grub finds /dev/nvme0n1p1 as the Windows Boot Manager and displays it, but this drive crashes when launching Windows.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to go to the UEFI menu and start Windows (successfully) from there?

Comment: In the UEFI Menu there seems to only be the ubuntu option

Comment: Run `grep -iR -A10 'windows boot manager' /boot/grub.grub.cfg` and post up output.

Comment: I'm getting no such file or directory

Comment: Sorry. There should be a forward slash instead of a period between the 2 grubs - ie `grep -iR -A10 'windows boot manager' /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: The boot,esp flags on your Windows partition are wrong.  The mount at /boot/efi of the Windows partition is wrong. Still, Windows should still appear in the EFI menu, maybe run boot-repair for a full report and post the link -- make no changes yet.

Comment: I'm still getting no such file or directory. I reran boot-repair and am running into the same issue: I can see Windows Boot Manager in grub, but selecting it doesn't launch Windows - just returns back to the menu. The report is here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7RY2FRVqXK/

Comment: You are booted into Ubuntu, not Live Ubuntu? Try running instead `grep -iR -A10 'windows' /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. This should not give an error, if you can see the Window entry in grub. If you still get an error, can you post up or link output to `gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: I can see the Windows entry - however, the UUID Is for the /dev/nvme0n1p1 drive, where there's windows boot manager but not the rest of my OS.

Comment: The output is here: https://pastebin.com/Ltk8EksQ

Comment: Can you confirm that Windows is on partition nvme0n1p3, and the UUID for nvme0n1p1 is E606-4328?  you're not sure run `lsblk -o name,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid`.

Comment: Yep! Thats exactly the case